# Output game sound coded in Dolby Digital with a graphic cards HDMI?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dolbydigital

Is it possible to get Dolby Digital surround sound through the [GeForce GTX 660](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-660-oem/specifications) HDMI output while playing a game or similar. Not only with direct output from a DVD or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Seams like it should be possible reading [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2188832#edit25891292). Anyone who has tried it and can confirm this?

EDIT1: No, it does not clearly state that it encodes to Dolby Digital, only that it can play/output it.

EDIT2: [Reading further](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2251442#post33558180), it could only be done if the game encodes Dolby Digital or if the audio chip has the Dolby Digital Live feature.